# What is the motivation for using a second order approximation for KL divergence in this example?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, entropy, model-comparison, kullback-leibler

Consider the KL divergence between two discrete distributions P and Q:
with probabilities $p_1,...,p_k$,  and $q_1,...,q_k$

$I^{KL}(P;Q)= \sum^{k}_{i=1}p_ilog\frac{p_i}{q_i}$.

The notes then say that **we can make a second order Taylor approximation** about $q_i$:
to get $\frac{1}{2}\sum^{k}_{i=1}\frac{(p_i-q_i)^2}{q_i}=\frac{1}{2}\chi^2_{pearson}$.

(I understand that the main point of this is to show that the $\chi^2$ statistic that we use when doing goodness of fit tests between distributions is in fact an approximation of the KL divergence thus showing that the KL divergence is a fundamental quantity.)

1)Is there a reason apart from the fact that it leads to the $\chi^2$ statistic for Taylor-approximating $f(p)=plog\frac{p}{q}$?

2)why is it that a second order approximation is used specifically?

Comment: can you share your notes as well?

Comment: The questions go to the context, which you haven't provided, and therefore require us to speculate.

Comment: @whuber  I have quoted directly from the notes. It is from an undergraduate level introduction on entropy, with the focus not on technical details but on showing that entropy is a fundamental quantity that underlies many concepts of statistical learning. In the notes all that is said that a second-order approximation of the KL divergence between two discrete distributions yields the chi squared test statistic for discrete distributions.

Comment: Okay, but that leaves us wondering what would constitute an answer.  You appear to ask what is the motivation for making an approximation after previously stating the motivation is to approximate a chi-squared statistic.

Comment: ah true. I meant to ask: is there a general reason for wanting to approximate $f(p)=plog\frac{p}{q}$ ? i.e. does the log in some way complicate the computation of the KL divergence